# Jolt # index of array and null values in output

Tags: json, transform, jolt

How do I get rid of the below challenges?

1. `Relationship.item[]` is an array that should hold both values `key.sourceKey` and `RelationshipDetails` object. Should not create two item objects separately. `Relationship` should not be an array, it is the object. item is an array.
2. Why these ***`null`*** values occurs inside the `AlternateName.item[]` array ? How to get rid of these ***`null`*** values. not by removing operations.
3. How do I assign aliasKey and localKey back to 1st and 2nd objects of `AlternateName.item[1].key.sourceKey` and `AlternateName.item[2].key.sourceKey`
4. Is there a way to generate the `localKey` and `aliasKey` depending on the code?

**Current Input**:

```json
{
  "accountType": "ADMIN",
  "id": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA",
  "relationship": "DIRECT",
  "accountInfo": {
    "partyTypeCode": "RELATIVE",
    "source": "Facebook",
    "internalAccount": true,
    "category": "Father",
    "alias": "Relationship-alias",
    "localName": "Banglorean"
  },
  "accountAddress": [
    {
      "addressId": "0016u00000bsqfrAddId",
      "integrationId": "0016u00000bsqfrInt",
      "addressType": "office",
      "shipToAddress": "Y",
      "soldToAddress": "N"
    },
    {
      "addressId": "12316u00000bsqfrAddId",
      "integrationId": "12316u00000bsqfrInt",
      "addressType": "home",
      "shipToAddress": "N",
      "soldToAddress": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt spec**:

```json
[
  { 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountType": {
        "ADMIN": {
          "@2,id": "key",
          "#Master": ["MasterLabel", "key"]
        },
        "*": {
          "@2,id": "key"
        }
      },
      "@relationship": "rel",
      "accountInfo": {
        "source": {
          "Facebook": {
            "@2,category": {
              "Father": {
                "#0001": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relCode",
                "#DIRECT": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relDesc"
              }
            }
          },
          "Google": {
            "@2,category": {
              "Son": {
                "#0002": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relCode",
                "#INDIRECT": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relDesc"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "alias": {
          "#aliasKey": "AlternateName.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "#0001": ["AlternateName.item[#2].type.code", "AlternateAliasKeyCode"],
          "#Alias Name": "AlternateName.item[#2].type.desc"
        },
        "localName": {
          "#localKey": "AlternateName.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "#0002": ["AlternateName.item[#2].type.code", "AlternateLocalKeyCode"],
          "#Local Name": "AlternateName.item[#2].type.desc"
        }
      }
    }
    },
  { // conditional for the cases of "accountInfo.category" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "rel": {
        "DIRECT": {
          "#~0001": "&2"
        },
        "INDIRECT": {
          "#~0002": "&2"
        },
        "*": {
          "# ": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  { // generate "relationship" attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "key": "=join(~,@(1,&))",
      "rel": "=concat(@(1,key),@(1,rel))",
      "aliasKey": "=concat(@(1,key),'~',@(1,AlternateAliasKeyCode))",
      "localKey": "=concat(@(1,key),'~',@(1,AlternateLocalKeyCode))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "key": "key.sourceKey",
      "rel": "Relationship.item[#2].key.sourceKey"
        //"aliasKey": "AlternateName.item[#1].key.sourceKey",
        //"localKey": "AlternateName.item[#2].key.sourceKey"
    }
  }
    ]
```

**Output for the above spec**:

```json
{
  "Relationship" : [ {
    "item" : [ {
      "key" : {
        "sourceKey" : "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0001"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "item" : [ {
      "RelationshipDetails" : {
        "relCode" : "0001",
        "relDesc" : "DIRECT"
      }
    } ]
  } ],
  "key" : {
    "sourceKey" : "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master"
  },
  "MasterLabel" : "Master",
  "AlternateName" : {
    "item" : [ null, {
      "key" : {
        "sourceKey" : "aliasKey"
      },
      "type" : {
        "code" : "0001",
        "desc" : "Alias Name"
      }
    }, {
      "key" : {
        "sourceKey" : "localKey"
      },
      "type" : {
        "code" : "0002",
        "desc" : "Local Name"
      }
    } ]
  },
  "AlternateAliasKeyCode" : "0001",
  "AlternateLocalKeyCode" : "0002",
  "aliasKey" : "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0001",
  "localKey" : "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0002"
}
```

**Expected output:**

```json
{
  "Relationship": {
    "item": [
      {
        "key": {
          "sourceKey": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0001"
        }
      },
      {
        "RelationshipDetails": {
          "relCode": "0001",
          "relDesc": "DIRECT"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "key": {
    "sourceKey": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master"
  },
  "MasterLabel": "Master",
  "AlternateName": {
    "item": [
      {
        "key": {
          "sourceKey": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0001"
        },
        "type": {
          "code": "0001",
          "desc": "Alias Name"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": {
          "sourceKey": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0002"
        },
        "type": {
          "code": "0002",
          "desc": "Local Name"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "AlternateAliasKeyCode": "0001",
  "AlternateLocalKeyCode": "0002",
  "aliasKey": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0001",
  "localKey": "aaab-ccc-ddd-eeeAAA~Master~0002"
}
```

***Updated jolt which removed the null values***
Just placement changes of alias and localName ? removed Null values, what is the logic beyond this ?

```json
[
  { //transfrom to lowercase
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountType": {
        "ADMIN": {
          "@2,id": "key",
          "#Master": ["MasterLabel", "key"]
        },
        "*": {
          "@2,id": "key"
        }
      },
      "@relationship": "rel",
      "accountInfo": {
        "alias": {
          "#aliasKey": "AlternateName.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "#0001": ["AlternateName.item[#2].type.code", "AlternateAliasKeyCode"],
          "#Alias Name": "AlternateName.item[#2].type.desc"
        },
        "localName": {
          "#localKey": "AlternateName.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
          "#0002": ["AlternateName.item[#2].type.code", "AlternateLocalKeyCode"],
          "#Local Name": "AlternateName.item[#2].type.desc"
        },
        "source": {
          "Facebook": {
            "@2,category": {
              "Father": {
                "#0001": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relCode",
                "#DIRECT": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relDesc"
              }
            }
          },
          "Google": {
            "@2,category": {
              "Son": {
                "#0002": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relCode",
                "#INDIRECT": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relDesc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  { // conditional for the cases of "accountInfo.category" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "rel": {
        "DIRECT": {
          "#~0001": "&2"
        },
        "INDIRECT": {
          "#~0002": "&2"
        },
        "*": {
          "# ": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  { // generate "relationship" attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "key": "=join(~,@(1,&))",
      "rel": "=concat(@(1,key),@(1,rel))",
      "aliasKey": "=concat(@(1,key),'~',@(1,AlternateAliasKeyCode))",
      "localKey": "=concat(@(1,key),'~',@(1,AlternateLocalKeyCode))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "key": "key.sourceKey",
      "rel": "Relationship.item[#2].key.sourceKey"
        //"aliasKey": "AlternateName.item[#1].key.sourceKey",
        //"localKey": "AlternateName.item[#2].key.sourceKey"
    }
  }
    ]
```

Is there any better approach than the below
***Working Jolt spec***

```json
[
  { //transfrom to lowercase
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountType": {
        "ADMIN": {
          "@2,id": "key",
          "#Master": ["MasterLabel", "key"]
        },
        "*": {
          "@2,id": "key"
        }
      },
      "@relationship": "rel",
      "accountInfo": {
        "alias": {
          "#0001": ["AlternateName.item[#2].type.code", "AlternateAliasKeyCode"],
          "#Alias Name": "AlternateName.item[#2].type.desc"
        },
        "localName": {
          "#0002": ["AlternateName.item[#2].type.code", "AlternateLocalKeyCode"],
          "#Local Name": "AlternateName.item[#2].type.desc"
        },
        "source": {
          "Facebook": {
            "@2,category": {
              "Father": {
                "#0001": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relCode",
                "#DIRECT": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relDesc"
              }
            }
          },
          "Google": {
            "@2,category": {
              "Son": {
                "#0002": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relCode",
                "#INDIRECT": "Relationship.item[#2].RelationshipDetails.relDesc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  { // conditional for the cases of "accountInfo.category" values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "rel": {
        "DIRECT": {
          "#~0001": "&3"
        },
        "INDIRECT": {
          "#~0002": "&3"
        },
        "*": {
          "# ": "&3"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  { // generate "relationship" attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "key": "=join(~,@(1,&))",
      "rel": "=concat(@(1,key),@(1,rel))",
      "aliasKey": "=concat(@(1,key),'~',@(1,AlternateAliasKeyCode))",
      "localKey": "=concat(@(1,key),'~',@(1,AlternateLocalKeyCode))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "key": "key.sourceKey",
      "rel": "Relationship.item[#2].key.sourceKey",
      "aliasKey": "AlternateName.item[#1].key.sourceKey",
      "localKey": "AlternateName.item[#2].key.sourceKey"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
}
    ]
```

Comment: Would be better you to share the expected JSON output as well

Comment: Added the expected output

Comment: What is the expected condition on accountinfo.category. Add complete details about your expected output.

Comment: updated the details